# Grouping the Data in a data frame based on conditions from more than 1 columns

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

**Problem Description :**

I am trying to calculate the recency , based on , what is the most recent value in Year column where the target achieved indicator was equal to 1 and in case the indicator column has 0 as the only available value for the Salesman + Year key, choose the minimum year in that case

**Data:**

```
   Salesman_ID  Year         Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator

 1     AA-5468  2012                                 1
 2     AA-5468  2013                                 0
 3     AA-5468  2014                                 0
 4     AA-5468  2015                                 0
 5     AA-5468  2016                                 1
 6     AL-3791  2012                                 1
 7     AL-3791  2013                                 1
 8     AL-3791  2014                                 0
 9     AL-3893  2015                                 0
10     AL-3893  2016                                 0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  Salesman_ID  Year Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator
         <chr> <dbl>                             <dbl>
 1     AA-5468  2016                                 1
 2     AA-3791  2013                                 1
 9     AL-3893  2015                                 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the package `tidyverse` I suggest you the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

Prashant_df <- data.frame(
    c("AA-5468","AA-5468","AA-5468","AA-5468","AA-5468","AL-3791","AL-3791","AL-3791","AL-3893","AL-3893"),
    c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016),
    c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
)
names(Prashant_df) <- c("Salesman_ID","Year","Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator")

Prashant_df <- Prashant_df %>% 
    group_by(Salesman_ID) %>% 
    mutate(Year_target=case_when(
        Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator==1 ~ max(Year),
        Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator==0 ~ min(Year)
        ))

Prashant_df_collapsed <- Prashant_df %>% 
    group_by(Salesman_ID) %>% 
    summarise(Year=max(Year_target),
              Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator=max(Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store both maximum and minimum year for each salesman, and the maximum of your binary variable.

```
newdf = df %>% group_by(Salesman_ID) %>% summarise(
  maximum = max(Year),
  minimum = min(Year),
  maxInd = max(Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator))
```

From this you can pretty much construct your resulting variable.

Comment: library(plyr)

newdf = df %>% group_by(Salesman_ID) %>% summarise(
  maximum = max(Year),
  minimum = min(Year),
  maxInd = max(Yearly_Targets_Achieved_Indicator)

detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Using Base R:

```
  c(by(dat,dat[1],function(x)if(all(x[,3]==0)) x[1,2] else max(x[which(x[,3]==1),2])))

   AA-5468 AL-3791 AL-3893 
      2016    2013    2015
```

This code is kind of a messy but produces the desired output: Here is the explanation:

first groupby `salesman_id`, then for that specific group check whether  all the indicators are zero, if yes, return the first year. else, look for the latest/maximum year among those which the indicators are 1